# ruby on rails change search route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, search, routes

my search form:

```
<%= form_tag("/search/index/", :method => "get") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :name => 'q' %>
<% end %>
```

my search controller:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @query = params[:q]
  end
end
```

current URL: `http://localhost:3000/search/index/?utf8=✓3&q=`

what i want it to be is `http://localhost:3000/search?q=`

or at least something similar to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your routes.rb just match the search to the index as

```
match "/search" => "search#index"
```

Comment: whats the new URL then? other than the original URL which will be the new one? if its possible, i would like it to be /search?q=query

Comment: /search is the new url, all of the parametrs you pass will be passed to the controller

Comment: why when i submit the form i have this: `search/?utf8=✓&q=` how could i fix this so it wont appear utf8 param or if it appear, it will be the correct format so it will work?

Comment: that would be a separate issue, has to do with submitting the form over GET